# Adjacency list model duplicate parent & children

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data, adjacency-list

**Hierarchical Data in MySQL Using the Adjacency List Model**

I have this table named `node_structur_data`

```
CREATE TABLE node_structure_data (
   id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   title VARCHAR(455) NOT NULL,
   parent_id INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES node_structure_data (id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Output:

```
id  title   parent_id
1   Division  NULL
2   Site 1    1
3   Paper     2
4   ms1       3
```

How can I duplicate a node and its children?
For example `Site 1`
The id & parent_id should be unique but the title should stay the same.

Expected Output:

```
id  title   parent_id
1   Division  NULL
2   Site 1    1
3   Paper     2
4   ms1       3
5   Site 1    1
6   Paper     5
7   ms1       6
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL? Can you add to your question how the table's content would be when the algorithm has been executed for the `Site 1` example?

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Version 8.0 @trincot

Comment: what is ms1      ?  its not even inside output . and you want it to be inside desired output ?

Comment: You'll probably have to write a stored procedure for that.

Comment: Forgot to add ms1 to output @AliFidanli

Comment: Is it not possible without stored procedures? @trincot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach first estimates the new max and then uses a recursive cte to find all children of the desired node 'Site 1' and determine their new possible `parent_id` if there were no other concurrent writes to the table.

I would recommend running the following in a [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) and [locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html) the table during the operation to prevent concurrent table modifications.

To test this approach I added some additional sample data which I have included below, however you may see the approach in a demo with your initial sample data [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cdJhsFgCCeoSxBo5i6GZmY/3)

See output of working db fiddle below:

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE node_structure_data (
   id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   title VARCHAR(455) NOT NULL,
   parent_id INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES node_structure_data (id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO node_structure_data
  (`id`, `title`, `parent_id`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Division', NULL),
  ('2', 'Site 1', '1'),
  ('3', 'Paper', '2'),
  ('4', 'ms1', '3'),
  ('5', 'ms2', '3'),
  ('6', 'os1', '4'),
  ('7', 'os2', '4'),
  ('8', 'gs1', '1'),
  ('9', 'hs1', '3'),
  ('10','js1','9');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select 'Before Insert';
```

| Before Insert |
| --- |
| Before Insert |

---

**Query #2**

```
select * from node_structure_data;
```

| id | title | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Division |  |
| 2 | Site 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Paper | 2 |
| 4 | ms1 | 3 |
| 5 | ms2 | 3 |
| 6 | os1 | 4 |
| 7 | os2 | 4 |
| 8 | gs1 | 1 |
| 9 | hs1 | 3 |
| 10 | js1 | 9 |

---

**Query #3**

```
select 'Possible Data Changes';
```

| Possible Data Changes |
| --- |
| Possible Data Changes |

---

**Query #4**

```
with recursive max_id AS (
    SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM node_structure_data
),
child_nodes AS (
    SELECT
        n.id,
        title,
        parent_id,
        m.id+1 as new_id,
        parent_id as new_parent_id
    FROM
        node_structure_data n
    CROSS JOIN
        max_id as m
    WHERE
        title='Site 1'
    
  
    UNION ALL
  
    SELECT
        n.id,
        n.title,
        n.parent_id,
        @row_num:=IF(@row_num=0,c.new_id,0) + 1 + @row_num  as new_id,
        c.new_id
    FROM
        child_nodes c
    INNER JOIN
        node_structure_data n ON n.parent_id = c.id 
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT @row_num:=0 as rn
    ) as vars
    
)
SELECT * FROM child_nodes;
```

| id | title | parent_id | new_id | new_parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Site 1 | 1 | 11 | 1 |
| 3 | Paper | 2 | 12 | 11 |
| 4 | ms1 | 3 | 13 | 12 |
| 5 | ms2 | 3 | 14 | 12 |
| 9 | hs1 | 3 | 15 | 12 |
| 6 | os1 | 4 | 16 | 13 |
| 7 | os2 | 4 | 17 | 13 |
| 10 | js1 | 9 | 18 | 15 |

---

**Query #5 - Performing actual insert**

```
INSERT INTO node_structure_data (title,parent_id)
with recursive max_id AS (
    SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM node_structure_data
),
child_nodes AS (
    SELECT
        n.id,
        title,
        parent_id,
        m.id+1 as new_id,
        parent_id as new_parent_id
    FROM
        node_structure_data n
    CROSS JOIN
        max_id as m
    WHERE
        title='Site 1'
    
  
    UNION ALL
  
    SELECT
        n.id,
        n.title,
        n.parent_id,
        @row_num:=IF(@row_num=0,c.new_id,0) + 1 + @row_num  as new_id,
        c.new_id
    FROM
        child_nodes c
    INNER JOIN
        node_structure_data n ON n.parent_id = c.id 
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT @row_num:=0 as rn
    ) as vars
    
)
SELECT title,new_parent_id FROM child_nodes ORDER BY new_id;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #6**

```
select 'AFTER INSERT';
```

| AFTER INSERT |
| --- |
| AFTER INSERT |

---

**Query #7**

```
select * from node_structure_data;
```

| id | title | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Division |  |
| 2 | Site 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Paper | 2 |
| 4 | ms1 | 3 |
| 5 | ms2 | 3 |
| 6 | os1 | 4 |
| 7 | os2 | 4 |
| 8 | gs1 | 1 |
| 9 | hs1 | 3 |
| 10 | js1 | 9 |
| 11 | Site 1 | 1 |
| 12 | Paper | 11 |
| 13 | ms1 | 12 |
| 14 | ms2 | 12 |
| 15 | hs1 | 12 |
| 16 | os1 | 13 |
| 17 | os2 | 13 |
| 18 | js1 | 15 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cdJhsFgCCeoSxBo5i6GZmY/2)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Great answer! It worked!